# How to say "your mom's house?"

Tags: orden-de-palabras

I'm pretty sure it's either "Tu casa de mami" or "Casa de tu mami"

Comment: I would have thought _La casa de tu mami_ sounded better still, but we should wait for the native speakers to give a definitive verdict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, literally as you are writing it: **La casa de tu madre**.

Now, depending on country, "family habits", formal or informal and context, *mom* could be translated to *madre*, *mamá*, *mami*, where *madre* is more formal and *mami* the less formal.

I think in english *mom* is more informal than formal, so it would be translated as *mamá* or *mami*, but in certain countries, like Spain, you never use *mamá* or *mami* referring to other person mother, unless certain very specific cases (joking f.i., or a woman that you consider something near a mother for whatever reasons, really special cases).
Basically *mamá* and *mami* are both diminutives used with affection, with love, so you don't use it with others' mom, but with your own mom! Specifically *mami* is very rare and most often used only by children.

As far as I know, in other countries, mainly latin american ones, they use *mamá* more often, so in these countries you could say "**la casa de tu mamá**" and it would be perfectly correct.

One last thing: **Tu casa de mami**... never, ever. That's like saying in English **your house of mom** (I'm not even sure if that's the correct literal translation). It's nonsense. **Tu casa** indicates that you are the house owner, **your house**, but **de mami** indicates that **mami** is the house owner, **of mom**. The house is yours, of your mother... what?

Don't use it.

Comment: The spelling mom is US. In The Uk we usually call her mum.